# unable to show controller over the current context with tabbar swift

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, tabbar

hello my controller is connected to `tabBar` and `navigationController` now  I want to show the controller over the current context then move to another controller B which must show the tab bar and back button of the navigation , currently i am doing segue its showing me black background.

Below is my `UIStoryBoard` layout.

[image]

i am moving to next `viewController` using segue like below

```
performSegue(withIdentifier: "second", sender: self)
```

Answer (score 0):

Select the segue and change it's attributes as following

[image]

//

set id for the VC and use this instead of a segue after you dismiss the model

```
let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Id")


self.presentingViewController?.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc!, animated: true)
```

Comment: yes its showing me controller over the current context but when i move to another controller it does not show me tab bar or navigation back button

Comment: How do you move from the modal to the next ?

Comment: i set storyboard id to  third controller which comes on popup  controller button but nothing happen unable to move

Comment: i use another code for move to another controller it says Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value